# Using PreviewCallBack without setting PreviewDisplay (ICS)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

At API level 10 I am able to do

```
_camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

and still have the preview call back fire on every frame after calling

```
_camera.StartPreview();
```

Now at API level 14 (ICS) the call back does not fire without a Preview Display being set to a valid and visible view.  Any ideas on getting around this, I don't care about the actual image beyond a processing standpoint and absolutely do not need to have it shown, and I feel like even having layered views and sticking the camera preview behind what I am doing is a huge CPU waste.

Comment: I suspect that this was closing a privacy loophole. Ensuring that you can't hide the preview behind other views would be the next loophole to close, assuming that this technique actually works.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the only problem with ICS. Even if you get it working using a PreviewDisplay (you need a SurfaceView with at least 1dp*1dp on the screen) on the emulator, some devices simply do not trigger the onPreviewFrame methode on ICS:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20999